# QProgressDialog not run a second time?

Tags: qt, dialog

I am working with QT creator and he has emerged a problem I could not solve ... I'm on a gui application, where I have a window with a button that calls "Scan" which when pressed runs a QProgressDialog while running a code that has a cycle heavy while .. up there all right, the problem arises when I press the cancel button of QprogressDialog, normally closed and asks if dialog.wascancelled cycle () break. everything perfect until the dialog closes the cycle is interrupted and return to my initial window .. But here is where the problem is if I press the button "Scan" opens again but his condition qprogressdialog wascancelled () remains true, which upon entering the cycle and ask if wascancelled () automatically goes without nothing ... As I can do to change the status of wascancelled () to false?, There are some property for this or I can do to achieve my goal to avoid breaking the cycle after entering a first time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call `QProgressDialog::reset()`.

Comment: wooooooh  thank you very much ... I love you hehe... was just what I needed .. thankss